React query prefetchQuery with Suspense
I'm working on my Next.js project with a server component page where I'm prefetching posts with HydrationBoundary. Here’s the server component:
'use server';
import PostList from '@/components/shared/PostList/PostList';
import SomethingWentWrong from '@/components/shared/SomethingWentWrong/SomethingWentWrong';
import { QueryClient, HydrationBoundary, dehydrate } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { getPosts } from '@/actions/posts';

const Page = async () => {
    try {
        const queryClient = new QueryClient();

        await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
            queryKey: ['posts'],
            queryFn: () => getPosts(),
        });

        return (
            <section>
                <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrate(queryClient)}>
                    <PostList />
                </HydrationBoundary>
            </section>
        );
    } catch (error) {
        return (
            <section>
                <SomethingWentWrong />
            </section>
        );
    }
};

export default Page;

After the initial prefetch, the data is cached, and I can see my posts without any delay:
'use client';
import React from 'react';
// components
import Post from '@/components/shared/Post/Post';
// utils
import { commentsCount } from '@/utils/comments';
// actions
import { getPosts } from '@/actions/posts';
// react-query
import { useSuspenseQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const PostList = () => {
    const {
        data,
        error: postError,
        fetchStatus,
    } = useSuspenseQuery({
        queryFn: getPosts,
        queryKey: ['posts'],
    });

    return (
        <>
            {data?.posts &&
                data.posts.map((post) => (
                    <Post
                        key={post._id}
                        id={post._id}
                        classNames={'[&:not(:last-child)]:mb-4'}
                        title={post.title}
                        description={post.description}
                        image={post.image}
                        createdAt={post.createdAt}
                        tags={post.tags}
                        viewsCount={post.viewsCount}
                        author={post.author}
                        likesCount={post.likes}
                        commentsCount={commentsCount(post.comments)}
                    />
                ))}
        </>
    );
};

export default PostList;

When I hard refresh the page, prefetching takes about 4 seconds to load the data, and during this time, it shows a blank page and doesn't even display the header which is included in the layout.
Is there a way to show a <Suspense fallback={...}></Suspense> while the data is being prefetched?
